# Filtering packets in Qtenv of Omnet++

Tags: omnet++

I want Omnet++\Qtenv to show only messages(packets) that have a special feature and this special feature should be specified with the filter expression. For example, do not display ACK messages and only display messages whose title contains the "ABC" phrase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Qtenv in the running simulation you may control what messages are not shown. Go to `File` | `Preferences` | `Filtering` and add filters for the excluded messages.

[image]

Comment: I want to show only packets sent from  Host1 node to Host2 node. How to can this requirement?